# Qt 5 General Questions about QT / QML and Widget customizations

Tags: qt

I am an iOS / Cocoa developer looking to port one of my apps to PC platform. I don't care to code multiplatform and maintain one app. I will continue using cocoa and cocoa touch for iOS Mac Development.
I have chosen to use QT 5 for PC, I am not sure if its wise choice but its easy and I can understand c++. If its not please point me to the correct direction.

My App is not hugely complicated, but needs some special customization e.g. ListView that looks like an iOS Table View, uses custom rounded windows with twitter bootstrap style search box and I want to monitor some global OS events like keystrokes, and what other applications the user is currently working with. I also use SQLite and AES encryption.

My questions is regarding UI customization.

1. Should I start studying and use QML for that? I am not sure what exactly it is, seems extremely simple CSS like, but I have the feeling is more designed for embedded devices  and have limitations...
2. Do I have access to the entire power of QT if I use QML ?
3. What other options I have to customise widgets instead using QML (e.g. in objective C we use subclassing and drawing whatever we want or handling events...)
4. I am inexperienced in windows platform. Should I use VisualStudio C++ instead of QT5? With the changes in ownership I feel somehow insecure.

Comment: You should try to ask these things as separate questions. Asking multiple questions in a single post is frowned upon. Perhaps with the exception of Question #4, which is too debatable to be a good question.

Comment: Btw, Qt Quick (QML) is great, but the support for desktop applications is not yet mature. Qt Widgets will provide the things you want, and I think you'd find them easier to learn. For now, at least. Qt Quick is rapidly improving.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All of my questions (except 4 which is general) is for ways to do Widget Customization. I am not sure why I need different questions for the same subject.

Comment: @BillKast Some of your questions can be found at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Quick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes you should. QML is declarative language which allows javascript to be executed within it. And you can do almost anything UI related with QML. If you don't have some particular UI element you can draw it in plain C++(Qt) and use it in the QML. So QML is the best choice for Qt development at the moment. It is not like CSS though, it is much more powerful.
2. Yes you have all the power Qt has and additional power which declarative language may offer - simplification of UI development process as well as modern decomposition of UI&logic.
3. You have this option in plain C++ Qt, you may subclass widget, redraw them, change behavior etc. This approach is inferior to the QML one.
4. This point doesn't make sense. Some people count Visual C++ like separate language which is wrong. You may count Visual C++ as C++ + some minor extensions MS compiler has. But it is as ridiculous to refer as GCC C++. So basically you can use Visual Studio with Qt almost without a pain if you use Qt integration add-in which is freely available. Or you can choose Qt creator, which some people count as superior to MSVS. It is up to you what to choose, but I believe for the novice it is much simpler to use Qt creator with Qt. But note you will need to have some compiler because Qt creator is just an IDE it should use some 3rd party compiler(either MS or GNU one)

Comment: @UmNyobe, can you elaborate your opinion?

Comment: @UmNyobe, this post shows nothing. Yes, there is a lack of some official ready-to-use components. But a) There are plenty of unofficial b) You can create whatever component you need.

Comment: Well you don't have anything to back up your words either. Anything unofficial is non standard, so whether it is qml or C++ is does not count.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QML Desktop Components to build easily your application:
https://web.archive.org/web/20121203050945/http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/06/06/desktop-components-for-qt-5/

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Quick_Components

Anyway I recommend you use Qt Widgets and Qt Style Sheets to costume your widgets:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html